# Move Row Column to bottomCenter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

How move `Column` wrap with `Row` to bottomCenter?

```
class DetailPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const DetailPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: kBackgroundColor,
      body: ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        children: [
          Stack(
            children: [
              destinationImage(),
              contentImage(),
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

Widget destinationImage() {
    return ShaderMask(
      shaderCallback: (bounds) {
        return LinearGradient(
          begin: Alignment.center,
          end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          colors: [
            kWhiteColor,
            Colors.black.withOpacity(0.80),
          ],
        ).createShader(bounds);
      },
      child: Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        height: 420.0,
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
            image: AssetImage('assets/image_destination1.png'),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Widget contentImage() {
  return Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
      left: defaultSideMargin,
      bottom: 80.0,
      right: defaultSideMargin,
    ),
    child: Row(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Text(
                'Rialto Bridge',
                style: whiteTextStyle.copyWith(
                  fontSize: 24.0,
                  fontWeight: semiBold,
                ),
              ),
              Text(
                'Italy',
                style: whiteTextStyle.copyWith(
                  fontSize: 16.0,
                  fontWeight: light,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          width: 24.0,
          height: 24.0,
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: AssetImage('assets/icon_star.png'),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        const SizedBox(width: 4.0),
        Text(
          '4.8',
          style: blackTextStyle.copyWith(
            fontSize: 14.0,
            fontWeight: medium,
          ),
        )
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

[image: Move widget]

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the `alignment` property on `Stack` widget.

Or you can wrap your `contentImage()` in a `Positioned` Widget

Try it on [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?null_safety=true&id):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: DetailPage(),
    );
  }
}

class DetailPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const DetailPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        children: [
          Stack(
            alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
            children: [
              destinationImage(),
              Positioned(
                bottom: 0,
                child: contentImage(),
              )
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget destinationImage() {
    return ShaderMask(
      shaderCallback: (bounds) {
        return LinearGradient(
          begin: Alignment.center,
          end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          colors: [
            Colors.white,
            Colors.black.withOpacity(0.80),
          ],
        ).createShader(bounds);
      },
      child:
          Container(width: double.infinity, height: 420.0, color: Colors.green),
    );
  }
}

Widget contentImage() {
  return Container(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 80.0),
    child: Row(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: [
        Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: const [
            Text('Rialto Bridge'),
            Text('Italy'),
          ],
        ),
        Container(
          width: 24.0,
          height: 24.0,
          color: Colors.amber,
        ),
        const SizedBox(width: 4.0),
        const Text('4.8')
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Didn't work get error `throw constraintsError;`

Comment: Ah sorry here the error.  [link](https://imgur.com/a/vRSLqiT)

Comment: I also included a small example you can put on DartPad to try to adapt to your use case

Comment: If using `Positioned` getting error like that but if using only `alignment:` is good. But, on the `Stack` widget will have lot of widget, if I set the `alignment:` with `Alignment.bottomCenter` will it make all widgets to bottomCenter?

Comment: your error is being caused because you are rendering a Column or Row inside a widget that doesn't limit size. Try wrapping  contentImage() inside Expanded widget or a SizedBox with a set size.

Comment: Yes, all widgets will be aligned bottomCenter if you set it directly on the Stack widget.

Comment: Can you give me sample? Or you need code `destinationImage()`? If you need, I'll update my code.

Comment: I posted a sample on my answer , but if you prefer you can send me a code I can run on my machine to help you fix the issue

Comment: I've updated the answer to include a minimun example that you can paste on DartPad. I also have set Row(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236974/discussion-between-caeruleum-and-pedro-pimont).

Answer (score 0):

Wrap contentImage into Positioned.fill

```
 Stack(
            children: [
              destinationImage(),
              Positioned.fill(child: contentImage()),
            ],
          )
```

full code

```
class DetailPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const DetailPage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
      body: ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        children: [
          Stack(
            children: [
              destinationImage(),
              Positioned.fill(child: contentImage()),
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget destinationImage() {
    return ShaderMask(
      shaderCallback: (bounds) {
        return LinearGradient(
          begin: Alignment.center,
          end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          colors: [
            kWhiteColor,
            Colors.black.withOpacity(0.80),
          ],
        ).createShader(bounds);
      },
      child: Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        height: 420.0,
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
            image: AssetImage('assets/image_destination1.png'),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Widget contentImage() {
  return Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
      left: defaultSideMargin,
      bottom: 80.0,
      right: defaultSideMargin,
    ),
    child: Container(
      color: Colors.red,
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
        children: [
          Container(
            color: Colors.white,
            child: Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Spacer(),
                  Text(
                    'Rialto Bridge',
                    style: whiteTextStyle.copyWith(
                      fontSize: 24.0,
                      fontWeight: semiBold,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    'Italy',
                    style: whiteTextStyle.copyWith(
                      fontSize: 16.0,
                      fontWeight: light,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            width: 24.0,
            height: 24.0,
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.green,
              image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage('assets/icon_star.png'),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(width: 4.0),
          Text(
            '4.8',
            style: blackTextStyle.copyWith(
              fontSize: 14.0,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```